# Grub-customizer does not install on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

I have been able to install Grub-customize on different versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint. However in Ubuntu version 20.04, it says that the repository is not secure and does not allow installation.

Comment: We will likely need more details. You should copy/paste the entire error as well as detail all of the steps needed to reproduce the error. Include all commands you've used.

Comment: @Nmath No additional details are required. In Ubuntu 20.04 just run `sudo apt install grub-customizer` to install the grub-customizer package from the default Ubuntu repositories.